# Parameterizing the Container name in the Script of Azure Data Flow ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-data-factory

Trying to deploy the ADF data flow to multiple environments using ARM templates.
I was able to deploy a hardcoded script of the data flow. But I need to parametrize the storage account container in the script.

This is the part of the script

source(allowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tignoreNoFilesFound: false,\n\tformat: 'delimited',\n\tcontainer: '**containerName**',\n\tcolumnDelimiter: ',',\n\tescapeChar: '\\',\n\tquoteChar: '\"',\n\tcolumnNamesAsHeader: false,\n\twildcardPaths:['FolderName/FileName*']) ~> source1)

I did try the below, concat also doesn't work as there are many single quotes in the script

- @{variables('containerName')}
- @{[variables('containerName')]}

Is there a way to parametrize the script part of the Dataflow ARM

Comment: Hi, Data flow parameters are used with **$** symbol. Can you try using `[($containerName)])`?

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT, [($containerName)] to be used in the ARM right ? coz I need to make it dynamic for different envs.. Let me try this and let you know.

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT, this is not working. It does not throw any error while deploying the ARM, but in ADF the data flow is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with ARM templates with a similar issue, then I tried something a little bit different that worked for me using a pipeline global parameter. This global parameter can be easily overwritten when deploying the ARM templates from Azure Devops Releases (i.e. moving the templates from different DEV to PROD data factories).

As dataflows doesn't have access to global parameters, I did this way: My dataflow has a parameter containerName, then I'm always overwriting it from the pipeline calling the dataflow, with the value of the global parameter with same name (using this  pipeline expression: @pipeline().globalParameters.containerName)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @hector, yes that is the option I have currently implemented, but that would be like passing the parameter from your invoking pipeline. We can parametrize the invoking pipeline. But I wanted to see if the can be achieved or if any has implemented it